# Change google maps center & water colour

Tags: google-maps, style

I have a website I've desigend and I would like to show a map under a contact form.  Unfortunately the contact form goes over my map.  I created it in Google My Maps.  I tried changing the lat & long in the map by manually typing over the coordinated.  Doing so moved the map to the right position but when I get the embed code it centres it again.

Is there a way to retain these changes?

[image]

Comment: might want to delete this question and add to the other one you asked...

Comment: @DPSSpatial I think it's a separate question.  The other one may require an API or some answer like this, but I suspect this one does not.  I had originally typed them both as one but then I thought it's a bit silly to ask two questions in one post, it kind of defeats the object.  If someone Google's this answer they don't need the answer to the other as well.